# Show only part of Qt Qml Drawer

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to show only half of a QML [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html). The idea is to keep some important information in the visible part of the drawer and then let the user show the full drawer with more information.

From the documentation I thought that the

`position` property should be suitable for this:

```
Drawer {
  modal: false
  interactive: false
  position: 0.5 // does not work
}
```

But setting the position does not have an effect. Is it possible to show only a part of the drawer?

Comment: Since Popups/Drawers normally inherit their size from their contents, is there some reason you want to do this via Drawer positioning, instead of toggling the visibility/size of your Drawer content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you may want to turn your concept inside out, and have the `Drawer` inherit its size from its contents, and have the contents change, rather than hardcode its size and manipulate its position.

Here is a full example that shows the idea. The drawer contains a RowLayout which contains "info" and "extra info" - the extra info's visibility is toggled via interaction, and thus changes the size of the drawer, which always stays at the 100% open position, but changes width automatically.

[image: drawer example gif]

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQml 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        height: root.height
        // width automatically derived from RowLayout child's implicitWidth

        onClosed: detailed.visible = false

        RowLayout {
            height: parent.height
            spacing: 0

            Rectangle {
                id: detailed
                color: "lightcyan"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                visible: false // when not visible, this does not add to the RowLayout's implicitWidth

                Text {
                    anchors {
                        centerIn: parent
                    }
                    text: "Extra Info\n Click to close"
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors {
                        fill: parent
                    }

                    onClicked:  {
                        detailed.visible = false
                    }
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                color: "lightpink"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 200

                Text {
                    anchors {
                        centerIn: parent
                    }
                    text: "Regular Info\n Click to open extra info"
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors {
                        fill: parent
                    }

                    onClicked:  {
                        detailed.visible = true // toggling visibility automatically makes the Drawer wider
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors {
            fill: parent
        }

        onClicked:  {
            drawer.open()
        }
    }

    Text {
        anchors {
            centerIn: parent
        }
        text: "Click to open drawer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is not exactly what I was looking for it is a good workaround Thanks!.